# LibGDX/Java Проблема с отображением текстур

Tags: java, libgdx

Из-за того что маленьких текстур в игре очень много, я решил их объединить в один файл. Для каждого пикселя записывается его цвет в файлик (с помощью Java библиотек). Когда расшифровываю этот же файлик (с помощью Java библиотек) всё прекрасно, но когда я это делаю в LibGDX игре, цвета пикселей слетают [image: картинка с битыми цветами в игре], после ещё одного обновления, картинка вообще слетает [image: слетевшая картинка].

```java
       //Чтение
        Pixmap image1 = new Pixmap(width, height, Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888);
        for (int y = 0; y < pixelsY.size(); y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < pixelsY.get(y).size(); x++) {
                java.awt.Color color = new java.awt.Color(pixelsY.get(y).get(x)); //я знаю что так не надо
                image1.drawPixel(x, y, new Color(color.getRed(), color.getGreen(), color.getBlue(), color.getAlpha()).toIntBits());
            }
        }
       //Запись
       //image - BufferedImage;
       for (int y = 0; y < image.getRaster().getHeight(); y++) {
           for (int x = 0; x < image.getRaster().getWidth(); x++) {
               buff = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(image.getRGB(x, y)).array();
               writer.write(buff, 0, buff.length);
           }
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Я частично решил проблему, я изначально записываю в файл с картинками, пиксели pixmap а не bufferedImage, но осталась проблема то что текстуры скукоженные.